# Inconsistency of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix $A$. Define $\phi_{A}:\mathbb{F}^{n}\to\mathbb{F}^{m}$.

Consider the linear system $Ax=b$.

My textbook states that the above system is consistent $\iff$ $b_{i}=0$
for $i>k$ where $k$ is the number of pivots in $A$ in RREF.

What is your intuition of this since I don't really understand why.

Comment: I think that you have misunderstood your textbook's statement. I suspect that they are saying that if the system $[A \mid b]$ is reduced to its row-echelon form $[R \mid c]$, then the system will be consistent if and only if $c_i = 0$ for $i > k$. In other words, the $b_i$ are **not** the entries of the original vector $b$.

Comment: Suppose then that $b_{i}$ were the original entries of the vector
$b$. What are the direct implications of that / what does it mean?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If $b_i$ refer to the entries of $b$, then it is not true that  "the above system is consistent $\iff$ $b_{i}=0$ for $i>k$ where $k$ is the number of pivots in $A$ in RREF", but I don't think that's the kind of "implication" you're asking about.

Comment: @BenGrossmann
I see, please could you correct me if I am wrong: 

If $R$ has a 0 row, and $c_{i}\neq0$ for $i>k$, then we would arrive
at a contradiction where $0=c_{i}$ for that non zero $c_{i}$?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right

Comment: @BenGrossmann Awesome, apologies I was looking far too deeply into this :D